# Using an object animation (functions) in jMokey Game Engine?

Tags: function, object, model, 3d, jmonkeyengine

I know i'm new to this, I did search a lot on how to use an Object's functions "like movement or jumping" in jMonkey, if you can tell me the keyword to search for, o the extension f the 3D object which can carry it's functions? I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check the tutorial ["Hello collision"](http://jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3%3abeginner%3ahello_collision)? I am not sure if that is what you are looking for. The CharacterControl helps you implementing a character that can jump and move around.